# Handlebars -error: The partial header could not be found

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm trying to make a header partial so I don't have to repeat the same html in the different view pages.

This is my configuration

```
var ehandlebars = require('express-handlebars')

module.exports = function(app) {
  var hbs = ehandlebars.create({
    defaultLayout: 'app',
    helpers: {
      section: function(name, options) {
        if (!this._sections) this._sections = {}
        this._sections[name] = options.fn(this)
        return null
      }
    },
      partialsDir  : [
          //  path to your partials
          __dirname + '/views/partials',
      ]
  })
  app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine)
  app.set('view engine', 'handlebars')
}
```

In my view file I have something like

```
{{> header}}
<div class="container"></div>
```

I've tried a few different solutions posted but nothing seems to be working for me. I keep getting -  Error: The partial header could not be found

Answer (score 0):

If your `partialsDir` is `/views/components`.

```
partialsDir: [
  //  path to your partials
  __dirname + '/views/components',
]
```

Answer (score -3):

{{>header}}

remove the space between header and >